# Linking macos's frameworks in Inline::C

Tags: macos, perl

Trying to use [Inline::C](https://metacpan.org/pod/Inline::C) and the `ApplicationServices.h` framework in Macos.

My simple code is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use 5.014;
use warnings;
use Inline Config => force_build => 1, clean_after_build => 0;
use Inline C => Config => libs => '-framework ApplicationServices';
use Inline C => 'DATA';

mmove(10,40);
__DATA__
__C__
#include <ApplicationServices/ApplicationServices.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void mmove(int x, int y) {
    CGEventRef move = CGEventCreateMouseEvent( NULL, kCGEventMouseMoved,    CGPointMake(x, y), kCGMouseButtonLeft );
    CGEventPost(kCGHIDEventTap, move);
    CFRelease(move);
}
```

Unfortunately, when running this got linking error.

```
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _CGEventCreateMouseEvent
  Referenced from: /Users/clt/.Inline/lib/auto/g_649d/g_649d.bundle
  Expected in: flat namespace

dyld: Symbol not found: _CGEventCreateMouseEvent
  Referenced from: /Users/clt/.Inline/lib/auto/g_649d/g_649d.bundle
  Expected in: flat namespace

Abort trap: 6
```

The pure `C` source code:

```
#include <ApplicationServices/ApplicationServices.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void mmove(int x, int y);

int main() {
    mmove(100,100);
}

void mmove(int x, int y) {
    CGEventRef move = CGEventCreateMouseEvent( NULL, kCGEventMouseMoved, CGPointMake(x, y), kCGMouseButtonLeft );
    CGEventPost(kCGHIDEventTap, move);
    CFRelease(move);
}
```

compiled with `gcc -o cl cl.c -Wall -framework ApplicationServices` works as expected.

**The question**: How to correctly pass the `-framework ApplicationServices` to the `Inline::C` linker? (my `use Inline C => Config => libs => '-framework ApplicationServices';`) doesn't works. (what I missed?)

Comment: It seems `Inline::C` is passing the `libs => '-framework ApplicationServices'` directly to [ExtUtils::MakeMaker](https://metacpan.org/pod/ExtUtils::MakeMaker) (see [line 833](https://metacpan.org/release/Inline-C/source/lib/Inline/C.pm#L833)). So I guess it could be an issue with (or bug) in `ExtUtils::MakeMaker`

Comment: @HåkonHægland uhhhh, thanx. But unfortunately i'm a beginner and the whole "things" behind the `Inline` is a pure dark magic for me... :/

Comment: Added [bug report](https://github.com/Perl-Toolchain-Gang/ExtUtils-MakeMaker/issues/393)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like it could be a bug in [ExtUtils::MakeMaker](https://metacpan.org/pod/ExtUtils::MakeMaker), but I have not been able to understand exactly what is the problem yet. In the mean time, the following workaround can be used:

```
use Config;
use Inline Config => build_noisy => 1, force_build => 1, clean_after_build => 0;
#use Inline C => Config => libs => '-framework ApplicationServices';
use Inline C => Config => lddlflags 
    => "$Config{lddlflags} -framework ApplicationServices";
use Inline C => 'DATA';

mmove(10,40);
```